# DotNetNuke and Angular router - disable navigation

Tags: angular, dotnetnuke, dotnetnuke-7

We are using `Angular` with CMS Platform (`DotNetNuke` aka `DNN`). Through DNN you can configure the menu navigation of the application, but as we are using Angular, we need to make use of the `Angular` router and ignore the `DNN` routing.

Our `Angular` router is working fine, but once I type in the browser URL `http://localhost:8001/mypage` the CMS platform throws an error saying that this page does not exist. This is because this page exists only in Angular routing and what is also correct.

Any idea how to disabled navigation in `DotNetNuke`?

Comment: Did you ever find a good solution for this?

Answer (score 0):

Do not disable routing.
You need to insert in your module `<base href="<%= Request.RawUrl%>">`

Look these codes can be usefull:
https://github.com/OPSI-srl/DNN-7.x-8.x-9.x-and-Angular-6-7
https://github.com/OPSI-srl/DNN-9.x-SPA-and-Angular-6-7

Matteo